# Android build failed with eas

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

when i run the command "eas build --platform android " i see this error: "✖ Build failed

Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information."

and when I run "expo doctor" I get the following message:
"Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.0
Found invalid:
@expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
(for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)"

and I don't know how to update this @expo/config-plugins

My Eas configuration file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.2.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "extends": "production",
      "distribution": "internal",

    },
    "production": {
      "node": "16.13.0",

    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by creating another project, then I just copied the files from the src folder and the package.json file. All did works perfect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).